# SQL combine two selects into one

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, select

The blog part of our site is wordpress.  What i would like to do to the home page of the main site is to take the most recent blog post excerpt and place it on the main site with a link to the article on the blog site.  I'm trying to get the SQL statement to work properly  and i think i have the main pieces, but want to put it into a single SELECT instead of two SELECTs.

The reason i have two SELECTs is to make sure i get the latest revision of the post.  First i try the revision SELECT to see if i get a row returned - if I do, i'm done.  If there is no row (no revisions on the post), use the second SELECT statement.

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM wp_posts
WHERE post_type = 'revision'
    AND post_parent IN (SELECT [object_id]
                FROM wp_term_relationships
                WHERE term_taxonomy_id = 3)
ORDER BY post_modified DESC

SELECT TOP 1 * FROM wp_posts
WHERE id IN (SELECT [object_id]
            FROM wp_term_relationships
            WHERE term_taxonomy_id = 3)
ORDER BY post_modified DESC
```

How can I combine these two SELECTs into a single SELECT so I can be assured of always getting a row back (i.e. the most recent blog post)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing that comes to mind is to use UNION and then you can take the first row of the result set:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM wp_posts
WHERE post_type = 'revision'
    AND post_parent IN (SELECT [object_id]
                FROM wp_term_relationships
                WHERE term_taxonomy_id = 3)
ORDER BY post_modified DESC
UNION
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM wp_posts
WHERE id IN (SELECT [object_id]
            FROM wp_term_relationships
            WHERE term_taxonomy_id = 3)
ORDER BY post_modified DESC
```

**UPDATE**

A simple subselect of the previous sql that returns the first record:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM (
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM wp_posts
WHERE post_type = 'revision'
    AND post_parent IN (SELECT [object_id]
                FROM wp_term_relationships
                WHERE term_taxonomy_id = 3)
ORDER BY post_modified DESC
UNION
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM wp_posts
WHERE id IN (SELECT [object_id]
            FROM wp_term_relationships
            WHERE term_taxonomy_id = 3)
ORDER BY post_modified DESC)
```

Comment: I was thinking about union as well, but not having much experience with it, i was sure about it.  Is there a way to select the top 1 from the union result set?  I guess not a big deal to return max two rows to the client and ignore anything more than the first one.

Comment: At the very least you can probably subselect; lemme update to that effect; but yes, retrieving only up to 2 records _should_ not have any significant effect on performance.

Answer (score 1):

Would this work for you?

```
SELECT TOP 1 wp_posts.* 
FROM wp_posts, (SELECT [object_id]
                FROM wp_term_relationships
                WHERE term_taxonomy_id = 3) relations
WHERE 
    (post_type = 'revision' AND post_parent IN relations) OR
    (id IN relations)
ORDER BY post_modified DESC
```

Or,

```
SELECT TOP 1 wp_posts.* 
FROM wp_posts, (SELECT [object_id]
                FROM wp_term_relationships
                WHERE term_taxonomy_id = 3) relations
WHERE 
   (post_type = 'revision' AND post_parent IN relations AND id NOT IN relations) OR
   (post_type <> 'revision' AND post_parent NOT IN relations AND id IN relations) 
ORDER BY post_modified DESC
```

Comment: Opps, forgot to copy that bit over. Thanks

Comment: Still, how do you maintain order WRT "First i try the revision SELECT to see if i get a row returned - if I do, i'm done. If there is no row (no revisions on the post), use the second SELECT statement."?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM wp_posts
WHERE (post_type = 'revision'
    AND post_parent IN (SELECT [object_id]
                FROM wp_term_relationships
                WHERE term_taxonomy_id = 3))
OR (id IN (SELECT [object_id]
            FROM wp_term_relationships
            WHERE term_taxonomy_id = 3))
ORDER BY post_modified DESC
```